When can the Weierstrass transform be represented as $e^{D^2}$?
The Weierstrass transform $W$ of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be defined as the convolution of $f$ with a Gaussian:
$$W[f](x) = \frac1{\sqrt{4\pi} } \int_{\mathbb{R}} dy\, f(x-y) e^{-y^2/4}.$$
It's not hard to show that the operator $W$ can also be written formally as $W=e^{D^2}$ with $D$ the differentiation operator.
For example, observing
$$\int_{\mathbb{R} } dy f(x-y)e^{-y^2/4}
= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R} } dy e^{-yD} e^{-y^2/4}\right) f(x)
= 2\sqrt\pi e^{D^2} f(x). $$
Furthermore, the Weierstrass transform can be applied to distributions and often produces regular functions, for example sending the Dirac delta into a Gaussian.

Another example reported in the Wikipedia page is $f(x)=e^{a x^2}$ with $\mathbb{R}\ni a< 1/4$, which gives via the convolution definition
$$W[f](x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4a}} e^{\frac{ax^2}{1-4a}}.$$
The same result can be obtained from $e^{D^2}$ using
$$D^{2n} e^{ax^2} = e^{ax^2} (-a)^{n} H_{2n}(\sqrt{-a} x),
%D^{2n} e^{-bx^2} = e^{-bx^2} b^{n} H_{2n}(\sqrt b x) $$
with $H_n(x)\equiv (-1)^n e^{x^2}D^n e^{-x^2}$ the Hermite polynomials (this connection is probably not accidental given that Hermite polynomials can themselves be written as $H_n(x)=2^n e^{-D^2/4}x^n$).
Computing the corresponding series should give back $W[f](x)$, using the expansion of a Gaussian in terms of Hermite polynomials:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} H_{2n}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4a}} e^{\frac{4a}{1+4a} x^2}.$$
Numerically it's also easy to see that the expressions coincide... as long as $a\in[-1/4,1/4]$. In other words, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{D^{2n}}{n!} e^{ax^2} = W[e^{a(\bullet)^2}](x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4a} } e^{\frac{ax^2}{1-4a}},
\quad\forall a\in[-1/4,1/4].$$
This is already a good example of what's stated in the page: $e^{D^2}$ doesn't always work as an expression, likely depending on the asymptotic behaviour of the derivatives, here the Hermite polynomials.

So the above shows in a simple case how the convolution and "operatorial" definitions of Weierstrass transform sometimes coincide and sometimes do not.
Is there any general result or observation to be made regarding when the expression $e^{D^2}$ actually works?
